# Write to a text file on the host computer using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, statistics, text-files

I'm curious if it's possible to write data directly to a file on the web server using javascript and **without jQuery**.

For example, if I have a file on my server named *stats.txt*, I would like to write data in it if a user clicks a given link.

I looked around everywhere but there's next to no info about writing data on the server.

You see, I don't want my users to save the stats file to their computers, because that would be just useless for tracking site statistics.

Also, if there is a different method for tracking statistics, again, **without jQuery**, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm curious if it's possible to write data directly to a file on the
>   web server using javascript and without jQuery.

Fortunately there's no such method neither in javascript nor in jQuery. This would have been a humongous security threat. But you could use a server side script (PHP, ASP.NET, Java Servlets, ...) that will write to the file and then send an AJAX request to this script.

Comment: It's not that important, I just wanted to know if that's possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible for more than obvious reasons.